# Multivariable density question

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Determine the center of mass of a triangular lamina whose density at any point is equal to its distance from the x-axis.

The triangle has vertices at (0,0)(5,11)(15,0).

I understand the process of finding the center of mass: that the double integral of $y$ over the triangle gives the mass, then doing integrals over the same bounds but of $xy$ and $y^2$ to find the moments, and finally dividing each moment by the mass to get the $(x,y)$ coordinate of the center of mass.

The answer I came to, (6.478,1.752) is apparently not correct though. Anyone care to check my math or help me find out what I did wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What bounds did you use for the integral of the triangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method sounds right; it seems the error is in the integration.   What bounds did you use for the integral?

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb I(f(x,y)) ~=~& \iint\limits_{T} f(x,y)~\rho(x,y)\operatorname d (x,y) \qquad &:T=\triangle (0,0)(5,11)(15,0), \rho(x,y)=y
\\[1ex] ~=~& \int_0^{11}\int_{Ay+B}^{Cy+D} y~f(x,y)\operatorname dx\operatorname dy & \textsf{For what values of }A,B,C,D\textsf{?}
\\[2ex] m~=~&  \Bbb I(1) & \textsf{the mass}
\\[2ex] \mu_X~=~&\Bbb I(x)/m & \textsf{the x-centroid}
\\[2ex] \mu_Y~=~&\Bbb I(y)/m & \textsf{the y-centroid}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I figured it out. I was missing the y-intercept on the upper bound. Thanks.